# Raise page number on first page of chapter with fancyhdr

Tags: chapters, page-numbering, fancyhdr, geometry

I am using the packages `geometry` and `fancyhdr` together.
I have the standard page layouts `plain` (footer with centered pager number) on the first page of a chapter and `body` (no footer and page number in header) in the rest of the chapter.
With `geometry`, I am NOT using `includefoot` as this would create space for a footer on all pages that don't have a footer as well.
However, because `includefoot=False`, the pager number on the bottom of a chapter's first page appears too low.
How can I raise this number without creating more footer space on all other pages?
I tried something like

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\vspace*{-30pt}\thepage}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{first}

\end{document}
```

but this moves the pager number into the text without creating whitespace above the page number.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround here: [Whitespace through empty figure environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569697/whitespace-through-empty-figure-environment)
which suffices for my needs.

Adding a `figure` to the bottom of the first page of a chapter with controllable whitespace moves the text such that the page number is not raised into the text anymore.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\vspace*{-30pt}\thepage}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{first}
\begin{figure}[b!]
  \vspace{20pt}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```