# Whitespace through empty figure environment

Tags: geometry, white-space

I am trying to alter my documents bottom margin for a single page. I have looked at all sorts of posts concerned with the `geometry` package and so on and have not found a solution for my needs. (See [Raise page number on first page of chapter with fancyhdr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569473/raise-page-number-on-first-page-of-chapter-with-fancyhdr))

If I simply add a

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\chapter{first}
\begin{figure}[b!]
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

at the beginning of that page (right after `\chapter{}`), if manage to achieve what I want.

Is there a way to control the height of that figure without using `\includegraphics[]{}`? Or another environment that lets me place whitespace at the bottom of a page with controllable height? Specifically, make it smaller than with the above code?

Comment: Well, you can insert a rule with zero thickness e.g. `\rule{0pt}{5cm}` but that will not give you exact control as the glue between lines and paragraphs might stretch a bit.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: To get the exact spacing use `\includegraphics` to set the image in a temporary box.  Then, the height of the box will be the amount of white space you will want to skip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\vspace` within the figure.

```
% marginprob.tex  SE 569697
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\begin{figure}[b!]
\vspace{1in} % adjust this to suit, negative to reduce the whitespace
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-5]

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem! I could have thought of this too...